# Is it possible to show multiple toastr messages in diferrent positions?

Tags: toast, toastr

```
 <script>
    var options1 = { positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width', timeOut: 0};
    toastr.error('Message1', 'Title1', options1);

    var options2 = { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right', timeOut: 5000}
    toastr.success('Message2', 'Title2', options2);
</script>
```

the success toast disappears after the 5s but it doesn't show on the bottom right

Answer (score -1):

The [demo site](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) makes use of a call to toastr.clear() before the change in form settings are recognized and the resulting toastr reflects the new options.  I would recommend incorporating this call into your code logic.